# State not causing render within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm trying to create a simple countdown app.
when console logging the counter it runs as expect yet when trying to convert the counter to actual mins/hours/seconds it seems like it gets stuck at 09:59 (when setting the time to 10 minutes for example).

this is the code :

```
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import sound from './assets/1.wav';

function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(null);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(null);

  var audioElement = new Audio(sound);
  let timer;

  //Countdown
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter((time) => time - 1), 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [counter]);

  const setTimer = (e) => {
    let newTime = time * 60000;
    e.preventDefault();
    timer = setTimeout(() => alertDone('Re'), newTime);
    setCounter(newTime);
  };

  //alert
  const alertDone = () => {
    window.close();
    audioElement.play();
    window.open('http://localhost:3000/', '', 'popup');
  };

  //convert miliseconds to hours
  function padTo2Digits(num) {
    return num.toString().padStart(2, '0');
  }

  function convertMsToTime(milliseconds) {
    let seconds = Math.floor(milliseconds / 1000);
    let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);

    seconds = seconds % 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    hours = hours % 24;

    return `${padTo2Digits(hours)}:${padTo2Digits(minutes)}:${padTo2Digits(seconds)}`;
  }

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <header className='App-header'>
        <form onSubmit={(e) => setTimer(e)}>
          <select className='text-black' onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}>
            <option value='1'>1 Min</option>
            <option value='10'>10 Min</option>
            <option value='20'>20 Min</option>
            <option value='30'>30 Min</option>
            <option value='40'>40 Min</option>
            <option value='50'>50 Min</option>
            <option value='60'>60 Min</option>
          </select>
          <button>Set</button>
          <div>Countdown: {convertMsToTime(counter)}</div>
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Would appreciate your help

Comment: Hi did you checked code I posted? I think thats the answer on your question

Answer (score 0):

Basically your code is working properly.

Problem is in `convertMsToTime` function.
For example, when you set time 10min that will be 60.000 milisecond then, you call `convertMsToTime` and it will calculate hours,minutes, seconds like this:

```
let seconds = Math.floor(59999/ 1000); //59
let minutes = Math.floor(599/ 60); //9
let hours = Math.floor(9/ 60); //0

seconds = seconds % 60; // 59
minutes = minutes % 60; // 9
hours = hours % 24; //0
```

Then when the time changes you will pass 59999-1 = 59998 miliseconds to same function, and you will get same result :

```
let seconds = Math.floor(59998/ 1000); //59
let minutes = Math.floor(598/ 60); //9
let hours = Math.floor(9/ 60); //0

seconds = seconds % 60; // 59
minutes = minutes % 60; // 9
hours = hours % 24; //0
```

ect..

And that's why you always get the same result,and it seems to you that countdown is stuck, because in essence the function always returns the same result as it should.

As you can see, the problem is that you have chosen too small a unit of time - milliseconds.

Choose seconds and everything should work as expected.

Here is the modified code:

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import sound from "./assets/1.wav";

function App() {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(null);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(null);

  var audioElement = new Audio(sound);
  let timer;

  //Countdown
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter((time) => time - 1), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [counter]);

  const setTimer = (e) => {
    let newTime = time * 60;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(newTime);
   /**This code will be executed every time the timer changes, ie a pop up window 
      will appear every second, so I commented on this */
// timer = setTimeout(() => alertDone("Re"), newTime);
    setCounter(newTime);
  };

  //alert
  const alertDone = () => {
    console.log("alert done");
    window.close();
    audioElement.play();
    window.open("http://localhost:3000/", "", "popup");
  };

  function convertSecToTime(seconds) {
    const d = Number(seconds);
    var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
    var m = Math.floor((d % 3600) / 60);
    var s = Math.floor((d % 3600) % 60);

    return `${h}:${m}:${s}`;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <form onSubmit={(e) => setTimer(e)}>
          <select
            className="text-black"
            onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="1">1 Min</option>
            <option value="10">10 Min</option>
            <option value="20">20 Min</option>
            <option value="30">30 Min</option>
            <option value="40">40 Min</option>
            <option value="50">50 Min</option>
            <option value="60">60 Min</option>
          </select>
          <button>Set</button>
          <div>Countdown: {convertSecToTime(counter)}</div>
        </form>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```